# Foreign Exchange orders simplification algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, sql-server-2008-r2, currency, graph-algorithm

This is an almost language-agnostic question, and not a homework. Ideally I would use C# and/or SQL server for solution.

Suppose that I have a function `GetExchangeRate(buyCurrency, sellCurrency)`. So, if 1 GBP is worth 1.6 USD, then `GetExchangeRate('GBP', 'USD') = 1.6` and `GetExchangeRate('USD', 'GBP') = 0.625`.

The orders in the system will be represented as the following triplets: `(buyCurrency, SellCurrency, buyCurrencyAmount)`. So, ('GBP', 'USD', 125.00) means buy 125 GBP with however many dollars it costs.

My goal is to save on transaction costs and cancel out the orders, including transitivity. Netting the buys and the sells between the same pair of currencies is easy to do, and easy to justify. Let's just say that I might have a business reason to simplify an order where I am buying GBP with USD, and also buying EUR with GBP, and so on ...

I want to simplify this set of orders transitively. I was thinking of building out a graph data structure (nodes are currencies and edges are buyCurrencyAmounts), even though the data would be stored in SQL tables, and applying the right algorithm to this. I thought of first doing a simple netting, followed by a topological sort on a DAG, followed by starting from the top, then walking in the topological order and "squeezing" the orders down, e.g. simplifying them.

The problem is that I will not necessarily have a DAG. But then, I will be likely simplifying the graph structure as I execute the algorithm, whichever one that will be.

What is the right data structure / algorithm that I should use for this? Should I be worried about the resulting precision? Are there some good approaches to not losing cents as I go? Can you recommend a good C# library that can handle this? Would it be crazy/inefficient/too much work to attempt this using only SQL Server 2008?

***EDIT:*** The fees paid for transactions are all built into the price (exchange rate). There is no fixed flat fee or anything like that.

Comment: Is that always the case that `GetExchangeRates(A,B) * GetExchangeRates(B,A) == 1`?

Comment: @unkulunkulu, in practice there is a so-called spread (the way the broker makes money), so my example was less than perfect. They way we model things now is such that this condition does hold. But, as I said, it will get complicated. There might be liquidity issues between some two exotic currencies, plus the spread, plus when the settlement will happen, because the price quoted for today, 1 week, 1 month ahead will differ. The easiest thing to do is to abstract this away with a `GetExchangeRate(...)` function, which will run in `O(1)`. We assume that the netting process never crosses midnight

Comment: cool. So, in the model we can assume that the equation holds. it's good from theoretical point of view, the algorithm will be a bit cleaner.

Comment: but we can assume the absence of arbitrage, right?
This is important because in connection with the above statement it means that direct conversion is always better than any chain of conversions.

Comment: @unkulunkulu, If it does not matter, then all the better. The arbitrage is theoretical. The brokers and other major players aren't so stupid to allow it in practice, meaning that transaction fees will eat away any "arbitrage".

Answer (score 1):

One possible technique is [minimum-cost flows](http://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem).

1. Determine how much of each currency to buy and sell.
2. Make a directed graph where the nodes are currencies, the arcs are possible conversions between currencies, and the arc costs capture the impact of spreads (I'm assuming that the listed rates are perfectly efficient and thus that any cycle of conversions multiplies to 1).
3. Use one of the polynomial-time algorithms described to compute a minimum-cost flow.

Comment: This assumes that the impact of the spreads is linear. This may not be a great assumption if there are per-trade costs or liquidity issues for large transactions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement *multilateral payment netting*.  The 'trick' is to create a new entity called the netting centre and re-route all payments through it.  See my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8643312/1077279) for the benefits of this approach.

The goal is to move from this situation (**before netting**):

[image: before netting]

to this (**after netting**):

[image: after netting]

Each subsidiary should end up with a single amount (either to pay or to receive) from the netting centre in their home currency which is the total of the countervalues of all the individual invoices they owe to any other entity in the group.

The basic algorithm is:

- Start with a table of invoices with *Payer*, *Payee*, *Currency* and *Amount* columns.  These correspond to the flows in the 'before netting' scenario
- Create a temporary table of subpayments which has *Entity*, *Currency* and *Amount* columns
- Iterate through each invoice adding a row to a temporary table for each Payer, Currency, Amount in the invoices table.
- Then to do the same for receipts, adding Payee, Currency and *negative* Amount.
- Roll up the subpayments into currency subtotals per entity.
- Convert the subpayment totals (applying spread if necessary)
- The temporary table now corresponds to the situation in the 'after netting' scenario

Rounding errors will be minimised because you will only be converting the totals.  Any results of the rounding errors will end up in the netting centre accounts.  The netting centre accounts will contain the currency subtotals which should be traded with an FX bank to convert them to a base currency, e.g., USD.  The rates dealt should be the ones used in the netting calculation, so once agreed with the FX bank, the calculation should be redone (and the totals will change very slightly).

(One of the advantages of using *multilateral* instead of *bilateral* netting is that any such FX requirements are all 'required' by the same single entity, *i.e.*, the netting centre.  Also, if you choose to charge a spread, *i.e.*, the buy and the sell rate differ, then any resulting 'profit' will also end up in the netting centre's account).

With regard to performing the actual calculation - it is simple enough to perform directly in SQL, but you may find there are enough legal and/or configuration options to warrant a more abstracted approach.

(For examples of legal issues: some governments do not allow conversion of foreign currencies in cross border transactions; others do not allow you to offset payments and receipts; some require permission from the central bank. Some countries with special requirements include Brazil, China, Malaysia, Russia, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like thinking of the set of transactions as a graph is over complex.  Just take every transaction in your set and add the currencies (i.e. add all GBP buy/sells, all USD buy/sells, EUR buy/sells).

You end up with the net buy/sell you want in each currency. Then just start picking out transactions based on the lowest spread (i.e. if you have lowest spread on EUR$ then pick out a EUR$ transaction - which may level some EUR or some $),  continue...

Comment: was thinking about this, but how to prove that the greedy algorithm provides the optimal solution?

Comment: Optimal in what sense? It's simply netting all the transactions. Are you trying to optimise transaction costs?  Ignoring transaction costs there is nothing to optimise - it's just netting.

Comment: James, you might be onto something. I can't say that I can see the whole solution, but let me try something in SQL. If/once I have something workable, I will update my question. By the way, yes, one of the goals is to optimize the total transaction cost, however, I cannot tell you the exact formula for it. It might be all in the price, and thus proportional to the amount being traded, or it is (likely) a combination of some fixed cost plus certain broker 'commission'. Let me try to look that up too.

Comment: Ok. One thing worth considering, once you've just netted all currencies - then assuming you're just trading the common liquid currencies there aren't that many ways of clearing all the buckets that you can't just try every possibility using whatever arbitrary complex formula for transaction costs.

Comment: @James, you cannot enumerate all the possibilities 'cause they will include dividing the existent currencies to needed ones in all the possible proportions, not just choosing which one to convert to another. It's possible that you have to spend 0.3 of your $ on EUR, 0.4 on GBP and the rest 0.3 on RUB and this would be optimal.

Comment: I'm not sure I see how that could be optimal in a real world scenario. It implies it would be more expensive per unit to do a larger trade than a smaller trade for a particular CCY pair. If your 0.3 RUB was all your RUB then your example would be covered. But every trade should empty one bucket. I suppose this ignores some liquidity constraints - but can these really be factored in??