# Transaction algorithm, what's the best one?

Tags: algorithm

i'll explain the matter.

**introduction**

I have a database containing some trasactions between people.
These trasanction contains lots of data but for the sake of this algorithm it's only needed 3 things : value of transaction, user giving money and user receiving money (I'm a student trying to build on my own a real world project for a group of friends).

**Steps**

This is not a real time processing but needs to be done only one or two time over long period of time.
The input to this algorithm will be the simplified transaction list and it'll get a map of what user gave and what user received  (eg from this [Mark, Sophie, 20], [John, Mark, 30] to this [Mark : -10 , Sophie : -20, John : +30])
After that i'd like to get the most efficient way reset all the members of the dataset to 0. (in that case it'd be mark give 10 to john and sophie give 20 to john, but for a larger quantity of transaction there will be optimal ways and sub-optimal ways).

**What i thought**

At first thought i think a greedy way is to get the max and the min and "equalize them" as result one (or at best both) should be 0 and going on like that untill there are none value left (the 0 value will be removed from the dataset not to loop or there will be a check if a value is not 0, probably the former).
I hope i explained it well, if not feel free to ask more. Is there a better way to minimize the numbers of transaction to equalize the dataset?

**Thanks all for your attention.**

Comment: To equalize the people, can someone give to many other persons, as well as someone can receive from many persons?

Comment: I think your first thought is perfectly adequate, it's `O(n)` and would let you *very* easily pull out the actual transactions that need to take place to equalize everybody, as well as determine if there's leftovers. Why did you post this question? Did you actually try your approach?

Comment: I googled for "minimize number of transactions settle tab". Here are two related Stackoverflow questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974922/algorithm-to-share-settle-expenses-among-a-group https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877728/what-algorithm-to-use-to-determine-minimum-number-of-actions-required-to-get-the/ and here is a java implementation of an algorithm https://github.com/soumyasethy/ShortestPath-CashFlow-Algorithm-Splitwise