# Method for splitting a group of units into another group units iteratively

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a method for splitting costs from a group of people owing money and paying another group of people that are owed money.

(E.g. think of something like a group of people pay for dinner, dessert, drinks, etc. and then the other people in the group needs to pay the payers back.)

I have two dataframes to represent these two groups:

```
owers_df = pd.DataFrame([236.94, 235.14, 220.14, 79.31, 96.96, ['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5'], columns=['Amount_Owing'])

payers_df = pd.DataFrame([38.88,798.57,31.06],['A1','A2','A3'],columns=['Reimbursement'])
```

The total of both dataframes are equal to each other, as the owers need to pay the payers.

My expected results is something like this:

```
data = {'Name':['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5'],'A1':[38.88,0,0,0,0],'A2':[198.07,235.14,220.14,79.31,65.90],'A3':[0,0,0,0,31.06]}
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
final_df = final_df.set_index('Name')
```

I am looking for a result where iteratively, person B1 pays A1, A2 and A3 until they have paid their amount.
In the example, person B1 pays A1 $38.88 which is all A1 is owed, then pays the rest of their owing amount to A2.
person B2 is next to pay, and since A1 has been fully paid, they pay their full amount to person A2.
This countinues until person B5 fully pays the owed amount to A2, and then pays the perfect remainder to A3 which is $31.06.

This can be verified by summing the final_df which should give the same results as payer_df.

```
final_df.sum()
```

What is the best method to get this outcome? The reason for this method, is that it is more efficient than getting 5 people to pay 3 people separately. This way, the most a person needs to action is 2 payments.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974922/algorithm-to-share-settle-expenses-among-a-group (Not Python specific, but discusses the algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it in an iterative fashion with a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-examples) and [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) as the default_factory:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

import pandas as pd


payments = defaultdict(dict)
for i in owers_df.index:
    if not owers_df.loc[i, "Amount_Owing"]:
        continue
    for j in payers_df.index:
        if not payers_df.loc[j, "Reimbursement"]:
            continue
        if owers_df.loc[i, "Amount_Owing"] >= payers_df.loc[j, "Reimbursement"]:
            payments[i][j] = payers_df.loc[j, "Reimbursement"]
            owers_df.loc[i, "Amount_Owing"] = (
                owers_df.loc[i, "Amount_Owing"] - payers_df.loc[j, "Reimbursement"]
            )
            payers_df.loc[j, "Reimbursement"] = 0
        else:
            payments[i][j] = owers_df.loc[i, "Amount_Owing"]
            payers_df.loc[j, "Reimbursement"] = (
                payers_df.loc[j, "Reimbursement"] - owers_df.loc[i, "Amount_Owing"]
            )
            owers_df.loc[i, "Amount_Owing"] = 0

final_df = pd.DataFrame(payments).fillna(0).T
```

Then:

```py
print(final_df)
# Output

       A1      A2     A3
B1  38.88  198.06   0.00
B2   0.00  235.14   0.00
B3   0.00  220.14   0.00
B4   0.00   79.31   0.00
B5   0.00   65.92  31.04
```