# Balancing collective expenses between multiple actors

Tags: algorithm, expense-splitting

Suppose three persons have contributed to the expenses of a trip: Adam has paid for the hotel, $150, Bob pays the gas, $60, and Charlie provides the food, $120. After the trip they want to balance the expenses.

The easy solution is that each expense is split between the three persons and individually paid by the other participants to the one that purchased the good in the first place.

Naturally, if Adam owes $20 to Bob and Bob owes $50 to Adam, it's equivalent to Bob owing $30 to Adam. Continuing this logic, Bob owes $30 to Adam and $20 to Charlie, and Charlie owes $10 to Adam.

Here's the catch: **this solution is not optimal**. The number of transactions can be reduced.  There is an amount of $10 that is first paid from Bob to Charlie and then from Charlie to Adam. Instead, Bob could add that $10 to the sum he is already paying to Adam.

In the end, Bob pays $10 to Charlie and $40 to Adam. Everyone has now covered the expenses with an equal amount of $110.

---

My questions are:

- When the goal is to find the way the expensens are balanced with the absolute minimum amount of transactions, what is the general solution to this problem with *n* actors? Traversing the paths from the most owing to the most owed can become computationally expensive, so it's not trivial.
- Can an NP-complete problem be reduced to this problem?
- Is there a well-known name for this problem?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877728/what-algorithm-to-use-to-determine-minimum-number-of-actions-required-to-get-the/

Comment: There's optimal, and then there's practical. Many bill payment solutions go for the latter, because expecting you to pay someone more than you owe them in the expectation they'll pay some of it to a third party to settle an unrelated debt is confusing. Also, being told you should pay $50 to Sally the Escort to settle your debt with Charlie might tell you something about Charlie he would rather you didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `c` people have paid more than their share (creditors), and `d` people less than their share (debtors). Since as per your definition, a solution is optimal if it implies a minimum number of transactions, the ideal case is that every debtor needs to make only a single transfer (they obviously have to make at least one). The question is then, can `X1`, the money owed to creditor 1, be obtained by an exact sum of amounts owed? Can `X2` be obtained by an exact sum of remaining amounts? And so on until `Xc`. In that sense the problem is related to the subset sum problem, as stated (a bit tersely) by n.m..

Comment: There are plenty of answers given in older question. Link to older question is given in comments of this question. This question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: @Dialecticus : perhaps you should rather tell the OP.

Comment: I know. Still some more flags are required to close this as an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem).

Comment: In what way is this reducible from subset sum?