# How to read and write data on spreadsheet on firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, spreadsheet, angularfire2

i am trying to write a very simple group expense app with front end ionic angular, back and firebase.

I did some research to manage data and algorithm; the best solution i think is pax’s is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/877803/8906296

But the solution includes a spreadsheet, i am working with firebase database. How should i struct my data which suitable with that solution or what you suggest to easily add, delete and calculate that data ?

my current data like this:

```
users/userid/profile/

groups/groupid/bills:

 {
    billdate:
    amount:
    description:
    payer:
    partipicants:
    }
```

for example; Jesse does a 90 USD shopping to split equally in 3 people (Jesse, Walter and Mike for example).

Jesse will get back 60 USD, Walter and Mike will give him 30 USD; balances are like this:

```
Jesse Walter Mike
60    -30    -30
```

After that,for example again, Walter paid a bill 30 USD and balances will be like that:

```
Jesse Walter Mike
60    -30    -30
-10    20    -10
```

app will calculate this data, and will show it like that:

```
Walter owes Jesse 10 USD
Mike owes Jesse 40 USD
```

what i am asking is, what is the most simple and effective way to struct that data in firebase for calculations.

Actually i have no idea how to do please assist me thanks.

Comment: Is there a question about a specific programming problem here? Or are you asking how to read and write data with Firebase? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I edited the question, thats not a specific programming problem. i am asking a suggestion for structing data.

Comment: The first issue is there isn't direct transactional tracking of who owes what to who. How do you know that if Mike owes 10, it's owed to Jess and not Walter? Add another person:  Jessie: 10, Walter: 10, Mike: -10, Leroy: -10. How would one know that Leroy owes 10 to Jessie, not Walter. You're going to need to think of these (and other) cases before implementing a structure.